# Python: Is it possible to split sentence into two line?

Tags: python

```
Sentence = "the heart was made to be broken"
```

How to split sentence for displaying in separate lines by using Python? (4 words per line)

```
Line1: the heart was made
Line2: to be broken
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do you just need a solution for this specific sentence, of do you have a more general problem?

Comment: Not for this specific sentence.  I have more than 50 sentences.

Comment: I think I said at the above that I want to display 4 words per line.

Comment: do you count punctuations as separate words (i hope not) or do you count them as a part of a single word. e.g. do you mean "word." is a word?

Comment: Your question is a modified version of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621906/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-by-every-nth-seperator-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Turn the sentence into a list of words.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words)
2. [Partition the list into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) of 4 words.
3. [Combine the partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426988/how-to-join-list-of-strings) into lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = 'the heart was made to be broken'

for i, word in enumerate(s.split(), 1):
    if i % 4:
        print word,
    else:
        print word

> the heart was made
> to be broken
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
import math

def fourword(s):
    words = s.split()
    fourcount = int(math.ceil(len(words)/4.0))
    for i in range(fourcount):
        print " ".join(words[i*4:(i+1)*4])

if __name__=="__main__":
    fourword("This is a test of fourword")
    fourword("And another test of four")
```

The output is:

```
>python fourword.py 
This is a test
of fourword
And another test of
four
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the solution for this problem which use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module. When you're trying to deal with sequence, be it a list or string or any other iterable, it's generally a good first step to take a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module from standard library

```
from itertools import count, izip, islice, starmap

# split sentence into words
sentence = "the heart was made to be broken".split()
# infinite indicies sequence -- (0, 4), (4, 8), (8, 12), ...
indicies = izip(count(0, 4), count(4, 4)) 
# map over indices with slicing
for line in starmap(lambda x, y: sentence[x:y], indicies):
    line = " ".join(line)
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic function:

```
from itertools import count, groupby

def split_lines(sentence, step=4):
    c = count()
    chunks = sentence.split()
    return [' '.join(g) for k, g in groupby(chunks, lambda i: c.next() // step)]
```

Which you can use like this:

```
>>> sentence = "the heart was made to be broken"
>>> split_lines(sentence)
['the heart was made', 'to be broken']
>>> split_lines(sentence, 5)
['the heart was made to', 'be broken']
>>> split_lines(sentence, 2)
['the heart', 'was made', 'to be', 'broken']
```

With the result you can do anything you want (including printing):

```
>>> for line in split_lines(sentence):
...     print line
...     
the heart was made
to be broken
```

Comment: Can you do this for a number of characters?

Comment: @BenWebb Yes, you can use a slightly modified version of the `split_lines` function above. Instead of operating on `chunks = sentence.split()` you operate on `sentence` directly.