# Pairs of two consequent words pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on language model and want to count the number pairs of two consequent words.
I found an examples of such problem on `scala` whith `slicing` function. Though I didn't managed to find the analogy in `pyspark`

```
data.splicing(2).map(lambda (x,y): ((x,y),1).redcueByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

I guess it should be something like that.
The workaround solution might be a creating function that finds the next word in array, but I guess there should be a in-build solution.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator

Comment: What is the question? Can you show an example of the data? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help. You can find other splitting methods here: [Is there a way to split a string by every nth separator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621906/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-by-every-nth-separator-in-python)

```
from itertools import izip

text = "I'm working on language model and want to count the number pairs of two consequent words.\
        I found an examples of such problem on language model and want to count the number pairs"

i = iter(text.split())

rdd = sc.parallelize([" ".join(x) for x in izip(i,i)])

print rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
```

> [('found an', 1), ('count the', 2), ('want to', 2), ('examples of',
>   1), ('model and', 2), ('on language', 2), ('number pairs', 2), ("I'm
>   working", 1), ('consequent words.I', 1), ('such problem', 1), ('of
>   two', 1)]