# split element inside list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to split the element inside the list based on certain length, here is the list `['Mar 18 Mar 17 Mar 16 Mar 15 Mar 14']`. Could any one help me to retrieve the values from the list in the following format:

`['Mar 18','Mar 17','Mar 16','Mar 15','Mar 14']`

Comment: have you tried some thing?

Comment: i have gone through the link and this doesnt solve my problem. The link explains about splitting a string in to two and set as constant, where as in my question the number of values may vary every time. schwobaseggl answer helped me to solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression based approach that would handle cases like `Apr 1` or `Dec 31` as well as multiple elements in the initial list:

```
import re

lst = ['Mar 18 Mar 17 Mar 16 Mar 15 Mar 14']

[x for y in lst for x in re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+ \d{1,2}', y)]
# ['Mar 18', 'Mar 17', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 15', 'Mar 14']
```

Comment: Exactly right approach (Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['Mar 18 Mar 17 Mar 16 Mar 15 Mar 14']

span = 2
s = list[0].split(" ")
s = [" ".join(words[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(s), span)]
print(s)
```

For me, this prints

```
['Mar 18','Mar 17','Mar 16','Mar 15','Mar 14']
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621906/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-by-every-nth-separator-in-python).

Comment: In this case It need manipulation. this will not provide desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

You can do it by the concept of regular expression (just by import re library in python)

```
import re

lst = ['Mar 18 Mar 17 Mar 16 Mar 15 Mar 14 Mar 2']

obj = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+[ ](?:\d{2}|\d{1})', lst[0])

print(obj)
```

**Output :**

['Mar 18', 'Mar 17', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 15', 'Mar 14', 'Mar 2']

Comment: `(?:\d{2}|\d{1})` can be simplified to either `\d{1,2}` or `\d\d?`

Comment: yes , we can simply with `\d{1,2}` but not with `\d\d` because date might be 1 digit integer or two digit integer in the range of 1 to 31 days

Comment: Hence the `?` to mark the second digit optional ;)

Comment: yes. we can do the second digit optional like `\d\d?`. Thanks alot :)

Comment: That's what I was suggesting all along in my first comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

```
>>> list = ['Mar 18 Mar 17 Mar 16 Mar 15 Mar 14']
>>> result = list[0].split(" ")
>>> [i+' '+j for i,j in zip(result[::2], result[1::2])]
```

**Output**

```
['Mar 18', 'Mar 17', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 15', 'Mar 14']
```