# Python: How to read a txt file next line by splitting its column number

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data and I am trying to read a txt file and read it line by line in excel by implementing a specific column number. For example:

```
0.12345 0.14251 0.12155...... 0.25541
```

And say after filling up 1000th column I want to put the next data into the next line:

```
0.12345 0.14251 0.12155...... 0.25541
0.15845 0.17151 0.19255...... 0.23572
```

I understand that if I have some kind of string (eg.~) after that number I want to split, this could be done using data.split like so:

```
data = testingdata.readline()   #reading a line from the .txt file 
data = data.split("~") #filter the ~ and put that into the next row
```

But in this case, I only know the column number I want to split rather than a known string. How could I possibly implement the same method here?

Thank you so much in advance for help!

Comment: What do you mean by "put data into the next row"? Are you writing back to the excel? Do you want a new string to use it elsewhere?

Comment: Just following up. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that allows you to split a string by specific number of columns. Hopefully you can adapt this code to your needs. I got the idea from here: [Is there a way to split a string by every nth separator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621906/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-by-every-nth-separator-in-python).

```py
s = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
delimiter = ' '
n = 3

numbers = s.split(delimiter)
group_indices = range(0, len(numbers), n)
rows = [delimiter.join(numbers[i:i+n]) for i in group_indices]
print(rows)
```

Output:

```
['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', '10']
```

Once you have a list of rows, you can do whatever you want with them. For example:

```py
text_block = '\n'.join(rows)
print(text_block)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```