# Pythonic way to turn a string of names into name pairs?

Tags: python

Basically I have a string like this:

```
names = "John Doe Jane Doe John Smith Jane Smith".
```

I want to convert it to look like:

```
outs =  ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "John Smith", "Jane Smith"].
```

Thanks.

Comment: `s.split()` can separate the string by space. But it seems that your rule is not simply by space.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: is string format is same, like `first_name last_name first_name last_name ....` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to split a string by every nth separator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621906/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-by-every-nth-separator-in-python)

Comment: Is this always first name and last name or does this string contain middle names?

Comment: You can not get what you want with your logic. What about a person with a middle name? I do not think this is even a python question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, it uses `more_itertools` to simplify a little bit.  It's `yield slices` of `length n` from the sequence seq.

```
from more_itertools import sliced      # import this lib first

# your names:  

outs = [' '.join(n) for x in sliced(names.split(), 2) ]

print(outs)
```

Output:

```
['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Smith', 'Jane Smith']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions to solve this.

```
>>> names = "John Doe Jane Doe John Smith Jane Smith"
>>> re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\b', names)
['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Smith', 'Jane Smith']
>>>
```

Comment: Like regex, it could be put this way too: `re.findall(r'\b[\w]+\s+[\w]+\b', names)`  But think it could be little challenging for the beginners..

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, and without imports, you could use a list comprehension, which is very pythonic

```
>>> [' '.join(x.split()[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(x.split()),2)] #list comprehension
['Jane Doe', 'John Doe']
```

If you only need to iterate over it once, a generator may be more suitable

```
>>> x="Jane Doe John Doe"
>>> print(' '.join(x.split()[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(x.split()),2)) #generator object
>>> for i in (' '.join(x.split()[i:i+2])for i in range(0,len(x.split()),2)): #iterating through the generator
    print(i)

Jane Doe
John Doe
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000000000000>
```

If you want to perform other transformations on the data, python has set comprehensions and dictionary comprehensions available.

```
>>> y='John Doe Jane Doe John Doe'
>>> {' '.join(y.split()[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(y.split()),2)}
{'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'} #set comprehension (to remove duplicates)
>>> {i//2:' '.join(x.split()[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(x.split()),2)} #dictionary comprehension (keys arbitrary)
{0: 'Jane Doe', 1: 'John Doe'}
```